# Export all regular expression matches in Textpad or Notepad++ as a list

Tags: notepad++, regex, textpad

In Textpad or Notepad++ is there an option to export all the matches for a regular expression find, as a single list?

In a big text file, I am searching for tags (words enclosed in % %), using regular expression `%\< and \>%`, and want all the matches as a single list, so that I can remove duplicates using Excel and get a list of unique tags.

Comment: If you use the RegexExtract plugin for Notepad++, it can remove duplicates for you and there is no need to post-process with Excel.

Comment: Linked: [How to copy marked text in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298962/how-to-copy-marked-text-in-notepad)

Comment: related to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66330516/961631

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html) and Find and Mark functionality in Notepad++.

1. Find the matches using regex (say `%(.*?)%` ) and replace it by `\n%\1%\n` , after this we will have our target word in separate lines (i.e. no line will have more than one matched word)
2. Use the Search-->Find-->Mark functionality to mark each line with regex `%(.*?)%` and remember to tick '**Bookmark Line**' before marking the text
3. Select Search-->Bookmark-->Remove Unmarked Lines
4. Save the remaining text.
   It is the required list.

Comment: I have one more file with <> as tags instead of % %, I tried with <(.*?)> and \n<\1>\n, but its not working, please help.

Comment: you are welcome :)
For me its working for <> also. Are there Nested <> ? 
Could you elaborate what exactly is 'not working' ?

Comment: I am trying to make a list of tags like before but these once have <>, I am using <(.*?)> instead of                                  %(.*?)% and \n<\1>\n instead of \n%\1%\n, this is the link to a sample file http://wikisend.com/download/158050/tags.txt

Comment: I tried it again with the provided text and using <(.*?)>, its working normally. I got the list of tags      
<Supplies>      
<hostname>.....and so on

Comment: Please mention the exact error/problem you are having. 
Might sound silly but remember to move cursor to top.I often do that mistake and search returns no result... :)

Comment: you were right :), I has set search direction to up, lol. Thank you so much Lamb, this has relay go me interested in regular expressions.

Comment: Step by step is great for discovering new possibilities in notepad++. The regex expressions didn't work for me (I'm a regex Noob).  '%' was not needed. I got mine working by testing it with regex101.

Answer (score 11):

Is doing this *in* Notepad++ a mandatory requirement?  Are you on Windows or some form of Unix?  If you’re on Windows, you can do it (partly) from the Command Prompt:

```
findstr /r "%[a-z].*[a-z]% %[a-z]%" your_file > new_file
```

`findstr` is vaguely inspired by `grep`, so this *new_file*
will contain all *lines* matching your search criteria; you can then use Notepad++ to strip out the unwanted text (to the left of the first % and to the right of the second one).

---

And, of course, if you’re on Unix,
you can do the equivalent task with `sed`. 
And if you have GNU `grep` (i.e., if you’re on Linux),
you can do it with `grep -o`.

Comment: from far the very best answer !

Answer (score 4):

There is a Notepad++ plugin which can copy matched regex expression to new file in new tab.
[RegexExtract](https://github.com/MojaveWastelander/NPPRegexExtract/releases/tag/v0_5)

> Because I didn't find any plugin for Notepad++ that can extract some text from current document or all files from a location with some additional settings (like case conversion), I decided to try to make it myself. (...)
> Plugin interface is pretty straightforward (...).
> (...)
> "Find", "Replace" and "Mask" fields use C++11 regex syntax.
> Extracting from files works right now only for those in UTF8.

**Edit** *Dialog input tailored to the question*

[image]

In the image you can see how to fill in the dialog. I assume that a word does not contain spaces, etc., only characters matched by \w. Notably:

- Use a pair of brackets, to allow selecting the word, without the percetange characters.
- Choose option *Extract with replace*, to select the first match. Otherwise, you will get a columnar output of all $1, $2, etc.
- Check *Skip $& ...* to leave out the complete matches.
- Check *Filter unique* to report each match only once.
- Click *Extract* to select get results. (*Search* only finds the matches, but does not report).

Comment: Nice plug-in, does exactly what was asked.

Comment: Seems not work with 64-bit Notepad++

Comment: This requires an older version of npp but I gladly made the switch. This is an invaluable plugin to me. I got it working on 7.5.6 32bit.

Answer (score 2):

In TextPad, you'd bring up the `Find` box as usual, then use the `Mark All` button.

From there, use `Copy Bookmarked Lines` function. (Edit menu > Copy Other > Bookmarked Lines.)

Comment: Personally, I do that exact operation so often that I've configured a keyboard shortcut for the Copy Bookmarked Lines function: Ctrl+Alt+c.

Comment: I came to this Question because I was searching for the Notepad++ question.  After many years as a loyal and unpaying Textpad user, I'm switching to Notepad++ (GPL).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in an online solution instead (since the notepad++ plugin doesn't work on 64bit) you can try [Molbiotools](http://www.molbiotools.com/textextractor.html) it can extract your regex completely without additional lines or with them.