# How to copy multiple-line-regex outputs into clipboard using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a fasta file containing genome sequences of multiple viruses.

Example:

```
>gi_138375030_Human_papillomavirus
GAAAGTTTCAATCATACTTTATTATATTGGGAGTAAAAAAAA...

>gi_94481944_Human_herpesvirus_3
GGCCCAGCCCTCTCGCGGCCCCCTCGAGAGAGAAAAAAA...
```

I want to extract only herpes virus entries, including the actual sequence, which is (in this file) always the line folowing the description.

The folowing regex works:

```
>.*herpes.*\n.*\n
```

It selects the description and the sequence lines.

I have found similar questions but all make use of the "bookmark line" function:
[Export all regular expression matches in Textpad or Notepad++ as a list](https://superuser.com/questions/477628/export-all-regular-expression-matches-in-textpad-or-notepad-as-a-list)

However, this only bookmarks the first line of the regex output, so I am unable to use the described solutions. If I use "find all in current document", it also only lists the first lines.

All I want to do is copy the output of regex into a new file. It is especially frustrating since it finds just above a hundred entries, which is just above the margin under which I would be willing to do it manually.

I would prefer a solution in Windows OS.

Comment: Opening the file in Excel and filtering there could be a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a copy of the file and then, on the copy, search and replace the *negation* of what you want:

`(?!>.*herpes.*)^(>.*\R)([ATGC]+\R)`

The above will (or ought to) find paired lines that **do not have herpes**. Couple this with a blank replace field, you will wind up with a file that has only what you are looking for.

Comment: It's brilliant however you missed dots at the end of a second line ^(?!>.*herpes.*).*\R[ATGC]+[\.]+\R+

Comment: @g2mk, I believe OP means "cont'd" by adding dots @ eol. «Following the initial line (used for a unique description of the sequence) is the actual sequence itself in standard one-letter code. Anything other than a valid code would be ignored (including spaces, tabulators, asterisks, etc...). Originally it was also common to end the sequence with an "*" (asterisk) character (in analogy with use in PIR formatted sequences) and, for the same reason, to leave a blank line between the description and the sequence» [FASTA format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format)

Comment: @SalvoF Heh - you right :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try to combine RegEx search with a macro (standard Npp shortcuts):

- Ensure that you have an empty line at file end - it is useful when using `Run macro to end of file` main menu entry.
- Search (`Ctrl+f`) for you sequence `>.*herpes.*\n.*\n` - don't allow to wrapping by file begin.
- Move to file begin (`Ctrl+Home`).
- Search again (`F3`).
- Start a macro recording (`Ctrl+Shift+r`).
- Go to line begin (`Home`) - you should be at the beginning of a first sequence line.
- Bookmark line (`Ctrl+F2`).
- Move cursor to end of second line (`Down` and then `End`).
- Bookmark the other line (`Ctrl+F2`).
- Search again (`F3`).
- Stop macro recording (`Ctrl+Shift+r`).

Now you should have a working macro. You can check it by playing it (`Ctrl+Shift+p`). If something goes wrong you can undo `Ctrl+z` or reload file from disk (another main menu entry) and try to record working macro again.

Then:

- Run macro to the end of the file.
- Now you can copy bookmarked lines or delete unboomarked ones and...

Answer (score 0):

Not an Npp solution; in Windows PowerShell:

```
Select-String "herpes" viruses.fas -context 0, 2 | % { $_.Line ; $_.Context.PostContext } | clip
```

Handier batch version:

```
@echo off
powershell "$what  = Read-Host String to search      ; "^
           "$where = Read-Host In which file         ; "^
           "Select-String $what $where -context 0, 2 | "^
           "%% { $_.Line ; $_.Context.PostContext }  | "^
           "clip"
```

Save it with a `.bat` extension (eg. "clipvir.bat") into the same folder where you've got `.fas` files. You may create a shortcut to the script on your quick launch / applications bar, or on your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following solutions:

```
use regex ">.*herpes.*\n[\nAGCTN]*" in **EditPad lite** and use its "search>copy_matches" option
```

or use:

```
cat virus_all.fasta | pcregrep --buffer-size 1000000 -M ">.*herpes.*\n[\nAGCTN]*" > herpes1.fasta
```

**in bash shell**

the regex works even if the sequence follows the header in multiple lines. In the second example you end up with a new file.